# Plotted raster output in R won't eliminate legend margin

Tags: r, r-raster, kernel-density

In R, I have a raster object generated from a kernel density analysis using the ks package. I convert this into a raster object (from the raster package) and try to draw that raster object to a PNG using plot(). I want the png to have exactly one pixel for every pixel in the raster object. Simple enough, right? By default of course, I get all sorts of extraneous junk added to the plot. I can remove most of this using the various settings in plot() or par(), but no matter what I do, I don't seem able to get rid of the space formerly taken up by the legend on the right side of the plot.

```
library('ks')
library('raster')

# generate the data
set.seed(1)
x = matrix(rnorm(1000,1,0.5),500)

xpix = 100
ypix = 100

# calculate the density function
k = kde(
    x,
    H=matrix(c(0.1,0,0,0.1),2),
    xmin=c(0,0),
    xmax=c(1,1),
    gridsize=c(xpix,ypix)
)
# convert to raster
r = raster(k)
# plot the image to PNG
png('file.png',width=xpix,height=ypix)
    par(
        mar=c(0,0,0,0),
        bty='n',
        bg='black',
        plt=c(0,1,0,1)
    )
    plot(
        r,
        legend=FALSE,
        axes=FALSE,
        plt=c(0,1,0,1)
    )
    # see that 'plt' did not change
    print(par())
dev.off()
```

If I check par before closing the device, I can see that the 'plt' value is not what I set it to; it shows the right margin, where the plotting area has been nudged over to make space for the non-legend. Sample code is above, and the image it generates is linked to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSg0L.png).

Incidentally, I was able to achieve the correct effect with the image() function instead of plot(), though that introduced it's own problems, namely that transparency no longer worked. Can I solve this with plot()? It's very frustrating that I'm so close but just can't seem to change the size of the plot area! I don't want to use another graphics package if there is any way to make the base function work.

Comment: Nate - do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve? What does the expected image() result look like?

Comment: I want the image to have defined colors breaks, and I would like to use a separate raster of the same dimensions to set the transparency of each pixel. I can set global transparency with image(), but not on a per-pixel basis. No margins whatsoever; I want a pixel in the input to be a pixel in the output.